# How to create coordinates on the form?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to create a form, which has two lines on it just like the two coordinates x-axis and y-axis. And then I want to add points on these coordinates. e.g.

- on this point(2,3) I want to add a point a
- on the point (-4,5) another point b
- on the point (-5,-7) another point c
- on the point (4,-6) another point d

How can I do this? Here are the two lines, which I have drawn:

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 190, 210, 350, 210)
e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 330, 90, 330, 300)
```

Comment: You will need to determine your origin, also the amount of pixels that each interval contains. You probably would be better off using a graphing control of some sort where all of the heavy lifting is done for you. something like http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/linesamples.html

Comment: the origin is at 330,210 
but i can't use graphical controls easily in this problem

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have your lines, use this for your points:

e.Graphics.FillEllipsis(Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(x,y,width,height));

x,y is the coordinate where you want the circle to be. Width height is obviously the size of your circle

Comment: I want to add points like (a,b,c) not to fill the ellipse
And I have mention before that my data for x and y axis is coming from gridview.